# NetBeans java desktop development re-open

Tags: java, netbeans

Months ago, I build a java desktop program using Netbeans as IDE. It is a normal program using java swing using jdbc, apache poi, and dans DBF. Actually I already finish built it and saved the file to the archive.

But then, my client ask me to do some modification. So yesterday I re-download netbeans (I already uninstall it) and open my archived project.

I can open my archived project in the new netbeand and re-build the .jar file. I can run the .jar file in dist folder but, I cannot run and debug the project using netbeans. whenever I press the run button, nothing happened.

**the run button**

[image]

I tried to run a hello world program and its work. Can anyone suggest what must I do? If I cannot run the program from IDE, I cannot debug it and make modification will be really hard.

This is the folder I open from netbeans. it has manifest.mf, and build.xml

[my project folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53yCW.png)

From netbeans, I choose file, then open the folder.

I really have no idea what must I do and I dont know anything else I should put in my question. Tell me anything information I need to solve this and I will update the question.

Thank you very much.

Comment: It sounds like you are opening the jar file, but not the project, so therefore Netbeans doesn't know what you are wanting to run when you click the run button.

Comment: How did you open a project? What sort of archive it is? Zipped project folder? If so, try: File -> Import Project -> From ZIP...

Comment: I'm opening the project which has build.xml and manifet.fm I will update the question

Comment: Do you see source code in 'src' folder?